# C How to terminate a thread blocked on ReadConsole()?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I'm trying to terminate a thread blocked on a ReadConsole() call from another thread. It doesn't work with terminateThread(i know it's not a good way to stop it) because when a restart that thread, somehow the thread is still there trying to return ReadConsole(). I've also tried to set an event from the other thread e wait for it on the other side, but i can't still figure out how to stop it.

Comment: Find a way to get status before committing to a blocking function. I had a look but could not find a similar console function, apart from the perhaps simple minded suggestion to use `kbhit()`.

Comment: i've tried khbit, it returns immediatly. i have to get input from console in a buffer and send it over a socket

Comment: Of course it does - that's the point. [`kbhit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx) is non blocking, and tells you if a key is waiting in the input buffer, which you then read knowing it will not block. Meanwhile, you can check if the thread is supposed to close.

Comment: Doesn't `ReadConsole()` have a timeout option? Blocking forever is never a good thing to do in multithreaded applications.

Comment: Agreed with @WeatherVane. Maybe you should try a regular `ReadFile()` with `stdin` opened in asynchronous mode...

Comment: One last (ugly) thing you could try would be to [`FreeConsole()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150(v=vs.85).aspx) your console, which would make the `ReadConsole()` fail, then `AttachConsole()` on your PID...

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, now i've managed to make it work with khbit. Another question: when i press enter in console, what should _getch return me?

Comment: \r, thank you again guys

Comment: @mychemicalro press the key, read the result, print it ;)

Comment: CancelSynchronousIo might also be an option, though I'm not sure whether it works on console I/O or not.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Unfortunetely it does not. I have tested it in Windows 7 and not `CancelSynchronousIo` nor `CancelIoEx` nor `WriteConsole` nor `WriteConsoleInput` does not unblock the `ReadConsole`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution which works under Windows 7, but I didn't test it specifically in a higher version of the Windows.

Additionally to `FreeConsole` which raises access violation under Windows 7, you can use:

```
CloseHandle(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE))
```

which unblocks `ReadConsole` w/o exception.

You can later use `CreateFile("\\\\.\\CON", ...)` to reopen console input handle.

CAUTION: You must check the handle type: `GetFileType(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)) == FILE_TYPE_CHAR` before try to close it.